# Can't Fetch an Particular Row from mysql Database

Tags: php, html, mysql

this is my first question here.
I am trying to generate pdf from a particular row of my database using mpdf. I want the code to download a particular row's data when needed. **A download link is beside every row. When the download button is pressed it will download that row's data.**
The code is working but it is fetching all the values from the db and assigning the values side by side.
Here is my generate pdf php

```
<?php

//==============================================================
//==============================================================
//==============================================================
include("mpdf/mpdf.php");
include "config.php";

$res = mysql_query("select date1, date2 from test");
if (!$res)
    die("query error : ".mysql_error());
$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','',32,25,27,25,16,13);
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0; // 1 or 0 - whether to indent the first 
level of a list
// LOAD a stylesheet
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('mpdfstyletables.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1); // The parameter 1 tells that this is     
css/style only and no body/html/text
$html = '

<center><h3>Test</h3></center>
<center>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Date 1</th><th>Date 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
$html .= 
    '<td>'.$row['date1'].'</td>
    <td>' . $row['date2']. '</td>';
}
$html .= '
</tr>
</table></center>
';
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2); 
$mpdf->Output('mpdf.pdf','I');
exit;
//==============================================================
//==============================================================
//==============================================================
?>
```

And Here is the view.php part for viewing the database

```
<html>
<body>
<style>
   table {
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}

td, th {

text-align: center;
padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #dddddd;
}

  textarea
{
  width:100%;
}
.textwrapper
{
  border:1px solid #dddddd;
  margin:5px 0;
  padding:1px;
}
    </style>
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('test')  or die(mysql_error());
$query=mysql_query("select * from test limit 0,10")  or die(mysql_error());
echo'<table border="1" ><th >Id</th><th>Date 1</th><th>Date 2</th>';
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  echo'<tr><td>'.$res['id'].'</td><td>'.$res['date1'].'</td>   
     <td>'.$res['date2'].'</td>
  <td><a href="gen.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?> Downlaod</a></td>
  </tr>';
}
echo'</table>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

[Screenshot of my view.php](https://ibb.co/fDUpo5)

Comment: You need to add a where clause to select the row you want.

Comment: add where condition in query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view page,

There is no array called `$row`. Rather `$res` holds your query's resultset.

Use this instead:

```
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo"<tr>";
        echo "<td>$res['id']</td><td>$res['date1']</td>";
        echo "<td>$res['date2']</td>";
        echo "<td><a href=\"gen.php?id={$res['id']}\">Download</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

In you pdf generating code, change:

```
$res = mysql_query("select date1, date2 from test");
```

To:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT date1,date2 FROM test WHERE id=".intval($_GET['id']));
```

Please, please, please upgrade your `mysql` functions to `mysqli_` immediately.

I recommend using a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to protect your query from malicious injection.  In the meantime, you can use [intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) as a lazy/temporary fix.

Comment: Can you give me a sample pdf generate code part? I'm not getting it. Thanks.

Comment: @NemoL Sorry, I don't have the time to replicate your project.  Surely you will be quicker to test your code because you already have all the bits and pieces.

Comment: When trying to view the view.php, its showing **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'id' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'** after changing the code as you said.

Comment: @NemoL on which line?  Does your url say `?id=something`?  Can you echo `$_GET['id']` before the query?  You may need to make some pastebin links again so I can scrutinize your updates.

Comment: On line 39.. **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'id' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\view.php on line 39**

Comment: @NemoL you created a private pastebin page, I cannot view it.  Please send me a public link.

Comment: The quoting needs to be adjusted to permit variables in the string.  Change: `echo'<tr><td>'.$res['ID'].'</td><td>'.$res['date1'].'</td><td>'.$res['date2'].'</td>
 <td><a href=\"gen.php?id={$res['id']}\">Download</a></td>
 </tr>';` to `echo "<tr><td>{$res['ID']}</td><td>{$res['date1']}</td><td>{$res['date2']}</td><td><a href=\"gen.php?id={$res['id']}\">Download</a></td></tr>";`

Comment: Wait.... what is the column name: `ID` or `id` ?  That needs to be fixed in my last comment.